# How to remove the RoomPlan Debug Metal HUD in iOS 16?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, realitykit, roomplan

**The problem**:

1. The console is filled with debug data making it impossible to log anything else.
2. The iPad screen shows a lot of metal HUD views making creating screenshots impossible.

**What I have tried**:

1. Setting the:
   `Scheme` -> `Diagnostics` -> `Metal`: `API Validation` flag to false or (true)
2. Checking the docu for several RoomPlan classes and structs for words like:
   debug, show, logging, log...
   `RoomCaptureSession.Configuration`, `RoomCaptureView`
3. Running the app in the `Release` build configuration (since the `Debug` was set per default).
4. Several google searches
5. Use a different demo project to verify if the issue is project-specific.
   [Official Apple Demo Project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/roomplan/create_a_3d_model_of_an_interior_room_by_guiding_the_user_through_an_ar_experience)

**Screenshots:**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Disable Metal Debug Data in Console

Go to Xcode 14.2 main menu:

<kbd>Product</kbd>  –  <kbd>Scheme</kbd>  –  <kbd>Edit Scheme</kbd>  –  <kbd>Run (Debug)</kbd>  –  <kbd>Arguments</kbd>  and add ***environment variable***.

```
// Name             Value
OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable
```

### Disable Metal Performance HUD

<kbd>Product</kbd>  –  <kbd>Scheme</kbd>  –  <kbd>Edit Scheme</kbd>  –  <kbd>Run (Debug)</kbd>  –  <kbd>Diagnostics</kbd>  and disable two options:

[image]

Or, when ***Developer Mode*** is enabled, disable it in iPadOS under

<kbd>Settings app</kbd>  –  <kbd>Developer</kbd>   (scroll down):

[image]

Comment: The man. The legend. Andy. Thank you. I would have never looked at the bottom of the developer settings on my iPad. Where did you learn this info?

Comment: ;) Thanks to nice tech talk ~ https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/tech-talks/110339/